# PHP imagecopy(): Setting X coordinate makes black area

Tags: php

I'm making a script that pulls in an image from an external URL. I am then using imagecopy() to merge the images because it is a transparent image. However, when I specify the X coordinate to be anything but 0, it creates a black area to the side of the image. Here is part of my code.

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng("URL...");
imagecopy($im, $src, 0, 0, 50, 18, 300, 300);
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the forums!

You will need to add these lines in the middle of those so your end code should be:

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng("URL...");
imagealphablending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
imagecopy($im, $src, 0, 0, 50, 18, 300, 300);
```

This should now work!

Comment: It is still not working, now the image has a white background next to a black bar. http://tracking.clubpenguincps.com/polo/polo.png

Comment: What are you merging from and to? are you just trying to resize?

Comment: I'm not re-sizing anything. The URL I am using is http://cdn.avatar.clubpenguin.com/%7B2dc0fb07-ccc0-44dc-b30a-443285b7f5f6%7D/cp?size=300&language=en&photo=false

Comment: I am merging to http://tracking.clubpenguincps.com/blank/polo.png and outputting http://tracking.clubpenguincps.com/polo/polo.png

Comment: Reading the php.net manual page, it seems like you need to add the `imagecreatetruecolor(80, 40);` function. Is what you have posted the full code? If yes then look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

Comment: I have $im = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/trackers/blank/polo.png"); in the code.

Comment: The way I asked this question was confusing, I will try to figure it out using the functions you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Solved: I set the image width from 300 to 250.

Comment: Im pleased you fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages getting transparency to work for me, modified for your case but not tested:

```
$newImg=imagecreatetruecolor($im_width,$im_height);
imagealphablending($newImg,false);
imagesavealpha($newImg,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($newImg, 0, 0, $im_width, $im_height, $transparent);
imagecopyresampled($newImg, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $im_width, $im_height, $im_width, $im_height);
imagecopy($newImg, $src, 0, 0, 50, 18, 300, 300);
```